# Asteriks in filename as wildcard not working

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I have a folder with many files like 20140720.457812.tmp and I try to count how many lines they have, I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=`more /folder/20140720*.tmp|wc -l`
```

but I get this error:

```
/folder/20140720*.tmp: No such file or directory
```

When I do `more /folder/20140720*.tmp|wc -l` in the terminal it works but not in the script.

Comment: so, are you sure that the file is existed because I have tried it and it worked for me

Comment: yes i'm sure! when i did this command in the terminal it worked for me too, but in the script it didnt work

Comment: Works in my script, too. I can't reproduce it with existing files.

Comment: Make sure you don't have more quotes than showed here. `more "/folder/20140720*.tmp"` would produce the error you are getting. Also check the paths, perhaps your script has a relative path but you are running it with a different working directory? (`cat` would be more appropiate than `more` here, btw)

Comment: The command you're showing is correct (you should use `cat` instead of `more`, but `more` works too). Either you aren't showing us the actual command from your script, or the files didn't exist at that point.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
lines= `more ./folder/20140720*.tmp|wc -l`
```

Adding `.` specifies the current working directory in the path name.

Comment: you have written single quotes instead of backticks

Comment: @Angel Like the guy before him. And he added a space infront of `=`, which should make the statement invalid.

Comment: @polym, <a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/145605/1">the original answer</a> didn't contain that space. I wasn't sure if it was better to comment or propose an edit, but considered it important so people didn't copy the "solution" and found the exact same problem as OP.